# Authorize different API endpoints via oauth2

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, authorization, openid-connect

I currently secure my API (running on k8s) with an [oauth2-proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/) which then redirects requests to the API.

As the scope of content (on API-level) should vary based on subgroups, these groups should be authorized only for their entitled scope. The Access Token provides the required subgroups affiliations but I cannot bridge the gap between the proxy handling the authentication and the API doing the authorization. I also just want to use a single API and oauth2 infrastructure.

Is it possible to pass the Access Token to the downstream API? What are best practices for this pattern?

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible: See the `--pass-access-token` and `--set-xauthrequest` options in oauth2-proxy.

E.g., I use this in `oauth2-proxy.cfg`

```
    # Get JWT in x-auth-request-access-token
    pass_access_token = true
    set_xauthrequest = true
```

combined with this in the nginx ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: x-auth-request-access-token # This holds the JWT (without 'Bearer ')
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: http://dev.k8s.ese-ia/oauth2-proxy/start # external URL!
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://oauth2-proxy.ese-ia.svc.cluster.local/oauth2-proxy/auth # internal service URL – must be fqdn to be reachable from the ingress!
```

Note that the header name is not `Authorization` and that there is no `Bearer`  prefix in the value. So the services using it might have to be changed. E.g, if you use Spring Boot, you will have to set a custom `BearerTokenResolver`.

(Bonus: If you use an AWS ELB with OIDC authentication instead of oauth2-proxy and an nginx ingress, the system is basically the same.  Only the header name is different.)

Comment: I know about `--pass-access-token` but what does `--set-xauthrequest` actually do? PS: It´s a fastapi, so I just need to parse the header, I guess, thanks :)

Comment: From the docs: `set X-Auth-Request-User, X-Auth-Request-Groups, X-Auth-Request-Email and X-Auth-Request-Preferred-Username response headers (useful in Nginx auth_request mode). When used with --pass-access-token, X-Auth-Request-Access-Token is added to response headers.`

You need this option to actually get the `X-Auth-Request-Access-Token` header, which the nginx ingress then can attach to the request before passing it downstream.

Comment: We always use the token from `x-auth-request-access-token`.  But you also can add more of the other `x-` headers to the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers` annotation.

In your case `x-auth-request-groups` might be an option: it's basically a decoded list of items in the token's scope claim.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to set the nginx response-headers route on the api´s ingress. Good point to use `x-auth-request-groups`.